# How to write simplejson in python 2.4

Tags: python, simplejson, python-2.4

I have an issue where I need to use `simplejson` to write some dictionaries to file using python 2.4 (yes, we're actively trying to upgrade; no, it's not ready yet).

Python 2.4 cannot use the syntax:

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dumps(data, outfile)
```

and I cannot find the correct syntax anywhere.  If I try using this:

```
sov_filename = 'myfile.txt'
sov_file     = open( sov_filename, 'w' )
filecontents = json.dumps( sov_file )
```

nothing happens.  The file is created, but nothing is in it.

So, does anybody know how to do this for python 2.4?

Comment: `dump` saves, `load` reads. which one are you trying to do?

Comment: In the first example, you are using `json.dumps` (a write activity) and in the second you are using `json.loads` (a read activity on a file you have opened for writing). Did you mean to do this?

Comment: oops!  Sorry about that--a copy/paste mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply needed to `close()` it.  I had it in the code, but was exiting before it executed.  I was accustomed to this not being necessary because I was using the csv writer in a python 2.7 script, for which the lines appear in the file without explicitly closing.

Answer (score 1):

To save JSON to file use `json.dump`:

```
sov_filename = 'myfile.txt'
sov_file = open(sov_filename, 'w')
json.dump(data, sov_file)
```

Comment: I'm trying to write to the file--my original post had a copy/paste problem.  This will try to read a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: And this does not work.  Regardless of using `dump` or `dumps`, the file will be created, but nothing is in it.

Comment: What kind of data do you put to `dump`?

Comment: @roninveracity, you are closing the file right? (e.g. `sov_file.close()`)

Answer (score 0):

The `with` syntax is syntactic sugar. The desugared equivalent is:

```
outfile = open('data.txt', 'w')
try:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
finally:
    outfile.close()
```

I'm not sure why simplejson isn't writing to the file, but you can work around that as well, by replacing `json.dump(data, outfile)` with `outfile.write(json.dumps(data))`